# How output data from database to table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

Good afternoon.

I am want select the data from the database to next table:
[image: 1]

**structure database:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExPRoG_Statistic_banners](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [banner_idn] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [banner_page] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [action] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [datetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [server_referer] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [ip] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [browser] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [id_firm] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

For select data i use script:

```
SELECT * FROM ExPRoG_Statistic_banners WHERE banner_idn='50927853'
```

But i see that select all data in table, me need use 31 select(for every day).

***Does anyone have any ideas how to choose data, using a smaller number of data requests?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      items INT
    , dt DATETIME
    , [user_id] INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (items, dt, [user_id])
VALUES 
    (1, '2013-08-08 00:00:000', 2),
    (2, '2013-08-06 00:00:000', 1),
    (5, '2013-08-05 00:00:000', 2),
    (3, '2013-08-03 00:00:000', 1),
    (2, '2013-08-02 00:00:000', 1),
    (2, '2013-08-01 00:00:000', 1)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
          items
        , [user_id]
        , [day] = DAY(dt)
    FROM @temp
    WHERE dt BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-31'
) src
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(items) FOR [day] IN (
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],
        [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20],
        [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])
) pvt
```

Comment: Tell me please how will be `[day] = DAY(datetime)` if `datetime='2013-08-08 00:00:000' ` ?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. `SELECT DAY('2013-08-08 00:00:000') = 8`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a `pivot`

```
select *
from
(
    select id, DATEPART(d,[datetime]) dm from yourtable) s       
pivot (count(id) for dm in 
([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],-- etc...
)
) p
```

Comment: Tell me please how will be `[day] = DAY(datetime)` if `datetime='2013-08-08 00:00:000' ` ?
P.S.: i get error - `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`